# Variable Coefficients tx = Ax Help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I ran into this problem on my differential equations homework set. Previously, the questions were in the form x' = Ax, and they were relatively straight forward and easy to complete.

I was gifted a hint that this problem revolves around variable coefficients.

I'm uncertain how to approach this problem.

My guess is we work backwards from the eigenvalue, to acquire r. And we can get the equations in terms of those variables? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried simply plugging the suggested solution into the differential equation?

Comment: I have not. I assumed you needed to solve for the general equation first. Then move independently to the next question. Should I solve using the suggested solution?

Comment: I was talking about the general equation.